# Upload a file with PUT method on POSTMAN

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, postman

Hi I'm getting an error when I try to Update image in the postman

My Controller

```
   $validator =    Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'category_id'=> 'required',      
    'product_name'=> 'required', 
    'product_description'=> 'required',      
    'product_img'=> 'required' 
 ] );
    if ($validator -> fails()) {
        return $this->sendError('error validation', $validator->errors());
    }
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id) ;

    $product->category_id = $request->input('category_id');
    $product->subcat_id = $request->input('subcat_id');
    $product->product_name = $request->input('product_name');
    $product->product_description = $request->input('product_description');
    $product->product_properties = $request->input('product_properties');
    $product->product_img =  $request->file('product_img')->store('images');
    $product->product_pdf =  $request->file('product_pdf')->store('files');
    if($product->update()){
        return $this->sendResponse($product->toArray() , 'Product Updated Succesfully');
    }
```

My PostMan row

```
"product_img":"Downloads/screencapture-file-C-Users-gkpro-Desktop-ui-Semantic-UI-master-examples-navbar-html-2019-01-03-20_31_47.png"
```

I get this error

Call to a member function store() on null

Comment: Please show us the entire controller. Also add a dd($request->all()); in your update as the first line in controller and add the result here

Comment: @Indra I Updated My Controller but   dd($request->all()) return Empty

Comment: @Indra The problem is i want to update image using json in postman  while in post methode i use form data  but i ca'nt use form data with put methode

Comment: Technically the whole approach id wrong because images should be treated separately, have a separate table, model, controller and be stored in a bucket, but since you're doing this you can't actually upload the image. You can change the update method to work with post however and that will work, but it will be a hack. And the validation should be done in a separate Request file.

Answer (score 13):

If you wanna use form-data to upload image with **PUT** method, here the trick,

add `_method: PUT` in form-data

[image]

Comment: if you use PUT method you can't use form-data, you have to use x-www-form-urlencoded.
have you tried what my solution?

Comment: The issue with using x-www-form-urlencoded is that you can only send text input. How do you upload an image or a file using the x-www-form-urlencoded.